# Is there any way to execute single mongo query for comparing an array of IDs?

Tags: mongodb-query

Following function will execute the mongo query multiple times,

```
function myFunction(array) {
    if (array) {
        newArray = [];
        array.forEach((element) => {
            const obj = await dbModel.findOne({ element });
            newArray.push(obj);
        });
    }
    return newArray
}
```

**Is there any possibility to acheive the result in just one execution of query?**

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this as following:

```
function myFunction(array) {
    if (array) {
       var newArray = await dbModel.find({$or:array.map(i=>({_id:i}))},"_id")
       
    return newArray
    }else{
     return []
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$in` like this:

```
model.find({
  "_id": {
    "$in": array
  }
})
```

Which returns an array of objects (the documents) which `_id` is in the original array.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iRcKGerrdzV)